# Should I use my DEM or ortho file to create my Hillshade layer?

Tags: dem, hillshade

I've just finished processing my DEM and ortho files, and have been asked to make my hillshade layer. I'm not sure whether to use my DEM or ortho file with this tool. What is the difference between those two files, and which one should be used with the hillshade tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer would be :  have a try, you'll see what happen ;)

To be more explicit : you need to understand what is hillshading. Hillshading (as in shade from a hill) is a way to recreate some impression of shade on a 3d looking like raster like on the image below. For this, you need altimetric values.

> "Hillshade function obtains the hypothetical illumination of a surface
>   by determining illumination values for each cell in a raster. It does
>   this by setting a position for a hypothetical light source and
>   calculating the illumination values of each cell in relation to
>   neighboring cells. It can greatly enhance the visualization of a
>   surface for analysis or graphical display, especially when using
>   transparency." ([Source](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/spatial_analyst_tools/how_hillshade_works.htm))

Ortho-images are essentially RGB values on 3 bands, like a classic picture you could take with your camera. Doing a hillshade on this kind of file would have no sense.

DEM represents altimetric values on one band.  A high value on this type of data will cast a longer shade than a low value, as in real life a mountain casts a bigger shade then a little bump.

You could hillshade some other kind of monoband values, like high concentration of a parameter, but it's more unusual.

[image: Hillshade of crater lake]

Comment: Thank you, that is an excellent explanation! I'm analyzing DEM images of aquatic plants that grows through a stream and stick out above the water surface. I'm trying to get a sense of their seasonal growth pattern from monthly image surveys. Based on your explanation, it seems like I need to use my DEM images with the hillshade function to get a quick sense of whether the vertical growth that occurs each month is captured in my images. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @adwillis My pleasure helping you :)